# Oracle - TOM's package for "ON CASCADE UPDATE"

Tags: oracle

Edit: *This question is different from the suggesed duplicate because the URL mentioned in that post is dead now, and on an alternate URL there is no link to download the package - that's why I decided to post a new thread seeking assistance in getting my hands on that package of Thomas Kyte.*

---

I need to add FKey Constraints ON UPDATE CASCADE - googling through I found a thread here on stackoverflow that points to a package written by Tom, but the link is no longer working :

http://asktom.oracle.com/tkyte/update_cascade/index.html

So I am wondering if someone got the Tom's package and can share with me or can help me implement the following FKey Constraint in Oracle :

```
ALTER TABLE 
  customer 
ADD CONSTRAINT 
  customer_address_id_fkey 
FOREIGN KEY 
  (address_id) 
REFERENCES 
  address(address_id) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: Looking through the [appropriate sections in the 11.1 SQL Reference Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2103997) I don't find an "ON UPDATE CASCADE" option. There's an "ON DELETE CASCADE", but nothing for "ON UPDATE". What version of Oracle are you using? Thanks.

Comment: The current link to the package is http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html

Comment: Thanks but this URL does not have a link to download the package ? BTW I am using Oracle 12c - Thanks

Comment: If you scroll to the end of the articla, to the section called **Downlaod**, you will find a link which downloads a `tar` file.

Comment: Thank you very very much, appreciate your help !